# How to use referenced libraries in exported JAR

Tags: java, gradle, packaging

I am using Gradle, and I need to know how to make sure that users of my Java program have the Gson library installed for use. Is there a way to do so? (I would like to avoid bundling it with my program, but if that's what it has to come to, then ok).

Comment: Don't bundle, document dependencies.

Comment: I figured, but how do you do this?

Answer (score 1):

There is no standardized way to distribute a standalone JVM application, but dependencies are almost always bundled. A good option for Gradle is to use the [gradle-one-jar](https://github.com/rholder/gradle-one-jar) plugin, which will produce a single executable Jar (`java -jar path/to/the.jar`) containing your code and its dependencies. Another option is to use Gradle's built-in [distribution plugin](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/distribution_plugin.html), which will produce a Zip containing your code, its dependencies, start scripts for *nix and Windows, and anything else you want to ship along with your application (e.g documentation).